# Strange output for netstat command

Tags: command-line, networking, mate, debian, netstat

I'm getting a strange output for the `netstat -tup`. What I mean by strange is I never got this output before when nothing connected to the network/internet (connected to the network, but not using it, ex - with firefox, thunderbird..) .

```
netstat -tup

Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
PID/Program name
udp        0      0 host:bootpc             _gateway:bootps         ESTABLISHED
-
```

I'm really curious to know what is mean by `bootpc` and `_gateway:bootps`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be rare that you would just so happen to catch a DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) IP address lease acquisition/renewal in progress.

Since your `netstat` command did not include the -n swtich, it is translating the two DHCP ports, port 68 to BootPc and port 67 to Bootps ("c"lient i.e. you, and "s"erver i.e. the gateway / router / dhcp server (I assume)).

The session should close quickly and you should see a similar time stamp to when you did that command in your dhcp client leases file at `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.interface-name.leases`, for example `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.enp4s0.leases`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response. So, the session is not closing quickly. It(`udp        0      0 host:bootpc             _gateway:bootps         ESTABLISHED` remains all the time. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Ash : Oh. Then I guess the DHCP lease handshake is not completing for some reason. Are you even using DHCP? Can you investigate at the packet level with tcpdump (or wireshark, if you prefer)? Suggest something like: `sudo tcpdump -n -tttt port 67 and 68`.

Answer (score 0):

On my laptop, this has the same IP as my wifi extender:

udp 0 0 :bootpc 192.168.1.137:bootps ESTABLISHED

And it is the only UDP protocol connection.

If I use -tup flags like you the extra column for PID is empty, just has a -.

- So its a continuous communication with my default gateway/extending packets on the road sort of.

Comment: Hi! Is this an answer or is it a question? It's not really clear. If it's an answer, please [edit] it to make it undoubtedly an answer. Else ask a new question by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button on the top right of the page. Thanks!